# JQuery Dynamic Combobox

Tags: jquery

Why within JQuery, the combobox add method doesn't seem to be recognized as with traditional html combobox here:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/dynamic-combobox-listbox-dropdown-in-javascript.html

Comment: I for one don't understand this question. What combobox add method?

Comment: Do you mean if you were to use a jQuery selector to get the combo reference rather than using `document.getElementById` why doesn't `.add` work?.. if that is the case it's because the selector returns a reference to a jQuery object instead of the element itself.

Comment: A select element is **not** a combobox. A combobox is a text box combined (hence the name) with a drop down menu. Are you talking about a jQuery plugin that simulates a real combobox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the actual DOM element in jQuery to call DOM methods on, [use .get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$("#myDropDown").get(0).add(option);
```

Please note though, there's another way to do this in jQuery:

```
$('#myDropDown').append($('<option></option>').val(myVal).html(optionText));
```

There's also the [Select Box plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) if you're doing a lot more with selects.

Comment: The later solution is the one which works on all browsers, plus IE (which doesn't like the 'new Option(value,text)' way)... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyFunction(myOption)
{
   $("#cbx").attr("innerHTML",myOption);
}
```

myOption should look something like this:

```
var myOption = "<option>" + whatever you want + "</option>";
```

I would ussually create my own Methods so I can Simply call e.g
AddDoc(doc);
Even `$("#myDropDown").get(0).add(option);` feels too long for me.
Id do something like `InsertOption(cbx,Option);`

 This is just an alternative way ^^.

```
function InsertOption(cbx,option)
{
   $("#"+cbx).attr("innerHTML",option);
}

function AppendOption(cbx,option)
{
   var opt = $("#"+cbx).attr("innerHTML");
   opt += option;
   $("#"+cbx).attr("innerHTML",opt);
}
```

Sorry if I made any mistakes ^^... junior prog ere :D

Answer (score 1):

If suppose we have 2 combo boxes

1. state
2. cities

When you select the state combo box then according to that value it will add items into cities combo box:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#DropDownList1").change(function () {

            if ($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text() == "Please Select") {
                $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
            }

            if ($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text() == "Andhra Pradesh") {
                $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Hyderabad") + "</option>"));
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Vijayawada") + "</option>"));
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Karimnagar") + "</option>"));
            }
            if ($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text() == "Tamilnadu") {
                $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Madhurai") + "</option>"));
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Chennai") + "</option>"));
            }
            if ($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text() == "Karnataka") {
                $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
                $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Bangalore") + "</option>"));
            }

        });
    });
```